# Python, Mechanize | Having issues with being logged out

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I'm learning python and running my first scraper using mechanize.

**Goal**: Login to a website, navigate to a list of URL's and return a chunk of text then write that to a CSV.

The code I'm using works great but as I run down the list I'm getting issues where after 10- 15 rows the entire html page is coming back rather than that chunk of text. Once the error happens it won't function correctly until I run the operation again but hits the snag after 10-15 again.

After looking looking at the html it looks as though I'm being logged out and can't figure out why. The URLs are all legit, if I test out getNum individually for all of the links it seems to work fine.

Last thing - The site needs Javascript and cookies to login

Here are what the functions look like

```
def get_Num(link): #takes in a URL, provided by the csv and finds the chunk of text I'm looking for
    import urllib2
    import cookielib
    import urllib
    import requests
    import mechanize

    # Browser
    br = mechanize.Browser()

    # Cookie Jar
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    # Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_refresh(False)  
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    # Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    # User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

    # The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
    br.open('https://www.website.com/login')

    #select the first form
    br.select_form(nr=0)

    #user credentials
    br['session_key'] = login
    br['session_password'] = pw

    # Login
    br.submit()
    print 'logged in'

    #open link
    br.open(link)
    html = br.response().read()
    position1 = html.find('text')
    position2 = html.find('>',position1)
    targetNumber = html[position1:position2]
    return targetNumber


def get_Info(inputFile,outputFile): # takes a CSV and runs getNum for ever url and then writes the whole thing to a csv
    import urllib2
    import re
    import csv

    with open(inputFile, "rb") as csvinput:
        with open(outputFile, 'w+') as csvoutput:
            reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
            for rowNum, line in enumerate(reader):
                vv = getNum(str(line[1]))
                line.append(vv)
```

Comment: FYI - You don't need to nest your `with open` statements. You can do: `with open(inputFile, "rb") as csvinput, open(outputFile, 'w+') as csvoutput:` on one line.

Comment: Thank you, I'll clean that up